# access a users predictions scores via has_many/belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, view, associations

Feel a bit ridiculous asking this question, but seems i still cant quite grasp it, thought i had but more learning needed it seems.

Ok so models set up like so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :predictions

end

class Prediciton < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :score
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What i want to do is grab attributes from the prediction model and the user model to use in my views. I am doing this in a separate controller

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

then in my view

```
<% @user.predictions.each do |u| %>
<%= u.name %><!-- this comes from user model -->
<%= u.score %><!-- this comes from prediction model -->
<% end %>
```

Seems like a few weeks off and ive forgotten the most basic principles

My current error is Couldn't find User without an ID

could someone please explain what i need to be doing here...really frustrating that i dont understand this

Thanks

EDIT

Ok so far i have come up with this in my view

```
<% @user.each do |u| %>
 <% u.predictions.each do |h| %>
  <%= u.name %><%= h.score %>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but my controller is just

```
@user = User.all
```

What i want to to is calculate the sum of all the score fields for each user

Would my controller then look something like this

```
@user = User.all
@scores = @user.predictions.where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today).sum(:score)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've changed your index route then there is no ID that you can grab from it.

If you want each user to have his own index of predictions then you can nest your routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :predictions
end
```

Then you'll have routes such as users/34/predictions

Also, as soon as you call predictions on user you're working with the prediction model, not the user:

```
<% @user.predictions.each do |prediction| %>
  <%= prediction.user.name %>
  <%= prediction.score %>
<% end %>
```

#### Update

Ok, you're asking a totally different question now, and kind of a tricky one too.

First of all, you can't call an association on a collection, `@users = User.all` (notice I named the variable as plural) returns all users (so a collection).

```
# this works:
@user = User.first
@scores = @user.predictions.where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today).sum(:score)

# this doesn't:
@users = User.all
@scores = @users.predictions
```

You could do the following but it's going to result in a lot of database queries which isn't good:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end

<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= user.predictions.where("fixture_date <= ?", Date.today).sum(:score) %>
<% end %>
```

On the other hand you could user `includes` in your controller, which will run only 2 database queries (once for users, once for all their predictions):

```
@users = User.includes(:predictions)
```

But it's a bit more complicated retrieving only certain predictions and summing them. I recommend you start a new question asking about that specifically.

Comment: ah i see, stupid me, still get same error though, is my controller correct do you think?

Comment: Unless you've changed your index route then there is no ID that you can grab from it.? would you mind explaining a bit more on this one please?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'm on the phone so hard to format, but run "rake routes" and you'll see some routes have an :id parameter and some don't

Comment: ok, so in my case I have a prediction controller but i want to show the users predictions in my Members controller (index action)..do i still need to nest routes? thanks for help by the way

Comment: i think that my question may have been a little to vague for what i wanted to achieve, i have updated if you wouldnt mind taking a look

Comment: thanks for the update, i did raise another question and got a working solution, your comments have helped my understanding a little more